# How long can I stay outside Germany with a regular German work permit?

Tags: working-visas, germany, resident-permit

I am a non-EU citizen. I work for a German company on a common work permit, *not the blue card*.

I am going to be on business trip to South America for 4 to 5 months. At the end of the project I will go back to Germany, which is my country of residence.

So, how long can I stay outside Germany with this type of visa?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that what you have is called not work permit (also you have that as well) and not visa, rather it is called a residence permit for the purpose of employment (§18 AufenthG). Then you are allowed to leave Germany for [6 months](https://www.berlin.de/labo/willkommen-in-berlin/aufenthalt/erloeschen-eines-aufenthaltstitels/). If needed, you can make an individual application to extend this time.

Comment: That's obvious, that's just the technical term for Visa - "Residence Permit for the purpose of employment".