# Leaving Germany for 1 year EU Blue Card Status

Tags: germany, blue-card

I have an EU Blue Card with my wife and two children (they are here due to family reunion) based in Munich.  I have read that EU Blue card is valid for one year if you stay in a non EU country. If you stay longer than 1 year, then it is cancelled.

My questions; 
- Is that 1 year time in total for the whole EU Blue Card validity period? For example my wife and children visit their relatives frequently and stay for 3-4 months at each visit. Should i sum all time periods they were out of Germany and check if total time sums up to 1 year or is it 1 year for each visit and nothing to be worried about?

- As a EU Blue Card holder, does this rule only apply to me? Are my wife and children allowed stay for any period in a non EU country? Or is it valid for family members also?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Niederlassung Renew](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/18137/niederlassung-renew) and [How long can I stay outside Germany with a regular German work permit?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/7064/13223)