# Regaining the right of residence in Germany (Niederlassungserlaubnis) after a long absence

Tags: working-visas, germany, eu, blue-card

I have a unique situation. I graduated from a German University and was working full-time for three years post graduation. During this time I received the EU Blue Card and later the *Niederlassungserlaubnis*. However after three years that is 2017 I moved to my home country for personal reasons and have been living away from Germany for two years now. I read that the permanent resident card remains valid only for 6 months of living abroad. Is it possible to get the permanent resident status back by any chance. Any help will be appreciated. Also what if I get a job in Germany now.

Answer (score 4):

You need to ask the corresponding Ausländerbehörde (before trying to enter Germany). A good idea would be to mention some personal issues that were the reason for you to leave Germany (because it could be a official reason to avoid the expiration of you residence permit, please see details [here](https://www.berlin.de/einwanderung/aufenthalt/erloeschen-von-aufenthaltstiteln/) and [here](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__51.html)). Actually, you should have asked them before leaving Germany, then it could be easier to avoid expiration of your Niederlassungserlaubnis.

May I also ask you if you really got Niederlassungserlaubnis and not "Erlaubnis zum Daueraufenthalt-EU"? Cause the latter one expires after 2 years for former Blue Card holders.

Comment: No I got the normal Niederlassungserlaubnis. I will try to get in touch with the Ausländerbehörde. Thanks.

Comment: How to get the "Erlaubnis zum Daueraufenthalt-EU" instead of "Niederlassungserlaubnis". Are the requirements any different?

Comment: Yes, the requirements are slightly different and you can apply for both of them. Check AufenthG §§9, 9a, 18c, etc. for the differences.