# Out of Germany more than 6 months. Is my Aufenhaltstitel still valid?

Tags: germany, residence-cards, german-citizens

I have an Aufenshaltstitel valid till 2020 September **(Aufenhaltserlaubnis)** **(Familienangehoriger)**, **(Anmerkungen §28 Abs.1 s. 1 Nr.1)** is what it says on my card.

I have been out of Germany for more than 6 months and recently when I spoke to the Auslanderbehorde they said my card is invalid as I stayed out of Germany for more than 6 months :O ....

What should be my next step to go back to Germany.

My wife who is a German by birth and I are both in my home country right now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Niederlassung Renew](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/18137/niederlassung-renew)

Answer (score 1):

Your residence permit was issued based on [§28 (1)(1) AufenthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0628).

- Spouse of a German citizen that **resides** in Germany

If you and your German spouse no longer reside in Germany, then the residence permit expires **automatically**, since the conditions it was issued against are no longer fullfilled.

Only if your spouse remained in Germany **and/or** you applied for an exception of the 6 month rule *before* leaving (need 12 months to take care of parents), would the residence permit had remained valid.

Once this condition is again fulfilled, a new residence permit will be issued.

You should contact the local German embassy / consulate, which will probably issue a D-Visa based on [§28 (1)(1) AufenthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0628).

---

> **[Section 28](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0628)** AufenthG
>   Subsequent immigration of dependants to join a German national
>
> - (1) The temporary residence permit shall be granted to the foreign
>
>   1. spouse of a German,
>   2. minor, unmarried child of a German,
>   3. parent of a minor, unmarried German for the purpose of care and custody
>
> **if the German’s habitual residence is in the federal territory**.
>   ...

---

**Sources**:

- [Act on the Residence, Economic Activity and Integration of Foreigners in the Federal Territory Residence Act](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0628)

Comment: I appreciate your fast reply and thank you for your time, Also I would rate your answer the 5-star solution for anyone in the same situation as me, I have written to the embassy and now waiting for a reply.