# How long can I stay outside of Germany to still keep my Permanent Residence Permit (Niederlassungserlaubnis)?

Tags: germany, resident-permit, blue-card

I'm a non-EU citizen.
32 years of age.
I did my Masters in IT (3 years) from Germany.
After my Masters i've been on a BlueCard visa (3.5+ years).
I'm currently eligible for a Permanent Residence (Niederlassungserlaubnis).
Due to some family reasons, I will have to stay outside of Germany for more than 6 months (probably even longer).

**Can someone please guide me (or preferably point me to the law) on how long can I stay outside of Germany without losing my PR status?**
Do I need to keep an address in Germany during that time period?

Comment: SImilar question was already answered: [Regaining the right of residence in Germany (Niederlassungserlaubnis) after a long absence](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/18137/regaining-the-right-of-residence-in-germany-niederlassungserlaubnis-after-a-lo)

Comment: If I read you correctly, you do not have the *Niederlassungserlaubnis*, you're merely eligible for it. Are you asking whether leaving now would make you ineligible? Or what would happen if you left immediately after obtaining the card?

Comment: @Relaxed the latter. I might have to leave Germany, once I obtain it.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule a residence permit will become invalid after a 6 month absence (§51(1)(7)) **or** the impression exists that you have left the country permanently (§51(1)(6)).

Exceptions exist for certain types of residence permits and certain conditions (§51(10)), which is then 12 months

- persons over 60
- Blue Card holders
- Permanent residence permit **after a residence of 15 years**

When applied for **beforehand**, a longer period can be granted. Taking care of a sick family member is one reason given as a sample for a valid reason for a longer period.

Giving up your residence (**Abmeldung**) will be considered leaving the country permanently. Doing so without notification of the Immigration authority **beforehand** that you intend to return, confirmed in writing, could lead to the residence permit becoming invalid immediately once they become aware that you have left.

---

**Sources**:

- [Erlöschen eines Aufenthaltstitels bei einem Auslandsaufenthalt - Berlin.de](https://www.berlin.de/einwanderung/aufenthalt/erloeschen-von-aufenthaltstiteln/#NE)
- [§51 AufthG - Termination of lawful residence; continued validity of restrictions](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1053)