# After permanent residency in Germany, how long can I reside outside of Germany and retain it?

Tags: germany, eu-spouses

I am Indian, have a permanent visa in Germany (not a passport) after marriage with a Romanian citizen. I have my business here.

Now I have some problem in India and I have to go back there. My question is if I stay for long-term in India can my PR status be cancelled?

If I don't take any money from government of Germany and I just ammelded here is it ok?  And it is possible if I go to 'auslander behorde' and tell my problem gave my visa back to them and go back to and after many years if I had plan to move back to Germany they gave me my status back?

My record is here good I never take social or arbeitloss from German, I do always a work then open my restaurant. Whats the solution here, as I don't wanna loss my status ?

Note we do not live together. If I buy a property here like house and gave it to on rent and gave taxes to government maybe then possible or not ?

Comment: Are you still married to the Romanian citizen and does your spouse live in Germany?  If so then it won't matter very much if you stay away so long as to lose your status.

Comment: Do you have a *multiple-entry visa*, an *Aufenthaltserlaubnis* or a *Niederlassungserlaubnis*?

Comment: Please see the info in my answers: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/11520/13223 and https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/11514/13223